# Online Video Course on Topology

Tags: general-topology, online-resources

I am at the beginning of learning topology, I found PDFs like topology without tears, but I wonder if there is a full university-like course online, on MIT open courseware I did not found anything and elsewhere I found stuff about algebraic topology, but not for more basic, set theoretical topics.

Comment: Frederic Schuller has some lectures on topology for physics students that are quite good. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_ and https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6SaWe7xeOp31Vo8cQG1oXw/videos.

Answer (score 3):

There is a full video course in Youtube: [General Topology - ICTP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXIcas22MtQ&list=PLLq_gUfXAnkl8bjQh-hGQ9u24xZP9x0dx).

It covers chapters 2,3,4 and 9 (topological spaces and continuous functions, connectedness and compactness, countability and separation axioms, the fundamental group) of a standard textbook: Munkres - Topology.

Comment: thanks, i yet dont see that it does cover stuff like nets, filters, ultrafilter,.., like more basic and detailed notions, although it covers quite a lot